# I have an array of objects in Javascript.How to loop through it to find the number of occurances of 'fname' key

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var eachMapping = [{"fname":"John"},{"fname":"John"}]; 
var count = 0;


    for(var i = 0; i < eachMapping.length; i++){
        for(var prop in eachMapping[i]){
            if(eachMapping[i][prop] = "fname"){
               count+=1
            }
        }
}

console.log(count);
```

Comment: You have that code... so?

Comment: I tried out your code, it works just fine.

Comment: This should do it: `var count  = eachMapping.filter(v => v.hasOwnProperty("fname")).length; `

Comment: As noted above, the posted code works just fine

Answer (score 1):

First of all: using a single "=" changes the value of eachMapping[i][prop] instead of checking for simularity. Try changing it to "=="

Second: U don't need to double loop. Try:

```
for(var i = 0; i < eachMapping.length; i++){
   if(eachMapping[i]["fname"]){
       count+=1
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
function count(obj) {
   var count=0;
   for(var prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
         ++count;
      }
   }
   return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two loops. Just one would do and to only check if property is there in obj or not.

```
for(var i = 0; i < eachMapping.length; i++){
       if(eachMapping[i]["fname"]){
           count+=1
        }
}
```

Comment: How about if one item in the array is `{"fname": "" }` or `{"fname": undefined }` or `{"fname": false }`

Comment: var eachMapping = [{fname:"John"},{fname:"Preeti"}];
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < eachMapping.length; i++){
       if(eachMapping[i]["fname"]){
           count+=1
           console.log(eachMapping[i]["fname"]);
        }
}

console.log(count); If you run this it is not matching exactly the 'fname' key I need to math the key

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use filter function here..

```
  var data =  [{"fname":"John"},{"fname":"John"},{"kname":"John"}];
```

as above data contains 2 object with key fname so it will return 2.

```
 data.filter(function(val, ind) {
return val.hasOwnProperty("fname");
}).length
```

Comment: How about if one item in the array is `{"fname": "" }` or `{"fname": undefined }` or `{"fname": false }`

Comment: What you want to count exactly, Occurance of key name or key having some proper value like fname  = "ancd" not fname ="" or fname = undefined ??

Comment: In your code the value of the property interferes with your check logic while it shouldn't. In other words, even if you have the `"fname"` property you may end up not counting it. So it's best to use `v.hasOwnProperty("fname")`.

Comment: Yes exactly, If you want to count only object having that key then hasOwnproperty is best. Have updated my answer. Thanks for pointing out.